# Is there a compelling reason to use an AMQP based server over something like beanstalkd or redis?

Tags: node.js, background, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

I'm writing a piece to a project that's responsible for processing tasks outside of the main application facing data server, which is written in javascript using Node.js.  It needs to handle tasks which are scheduled in the future and potentially handle tasks that are "right now".  The "right now" just means the next time a worker becomes available it will operate on that task, so that bit might not matter.  The workers are going to all talk to external resources, an example job would be to send an email.  We are a small shop and we don't have a ton of resources so one thing I don't want to do is start mixing languages at this point in the process, and I already see that Node can do this for us pretty easily, so that's what we're going to go with unless I see a compelling reason not to before I start coding, which is soon.

All that said, I can't tell if there is a compelling reason to use an AMQP based server, like [OpenAMQ](http://www.openamq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) over something like [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue) or [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) with a node client.  So, here we go:

Is there a compelling reason to use an AMQP based server over something like beanstalkd or redis with Kue?  If yes, which AMPQ based server would fit best with the architecture that I laid out?  If no, which nosql solution (beanstalkd, redis/Kue) would be easiest to set up and fastest to deploy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FWIW, I'm not accepting my answer yet, I'm going to explain what I've decided and why.  If I don't get any answers that appear to be better than what I've decided, I'll accept my own later.

I decided on Kue.  It supports multiple workers running asynchronously, and with cluster it can take advantage of multicore systems.  It is easily extended to provide security.  It's backed with Redis, which is used all over for this exact thing, so I know I'm not backing my job process server with unproven software (that's not to say that any of the others are unproven.)

The most compelling reasons that I picked Kue is that it provides a JSON api so that the client applications (The first client is going to be a web based application, but we're planning on making smartphone apps also) can add jobs easily without going through the main application facing node instance, so I can be totally out of the way of the rest of my team as I write this.  I don't need a route, I don't need anything, and it's all provided for me so I don't need to write anything to support this. This has another advantage, with an extention to provide l/p security only authorized clients can add jobs, so I don;t have to expose my redis server to client applications directly.  It also has a built in web console and the API allows the client to pull back lists of jobs associated with a given user very easily, so we can show the user all of their scheduled tasks in a nifty calendar view with 0 effort on my part.

The other compelling reason is the lack of steep learning curve associated with getting redis and Kue going for me.  I've set up redis before, and Kue is simple and effective.

Yes, I'm a lazy developer, but I'm the good kind of lazy developer.

UPDATE:

I have it working and doing jobs, the throughput is amazing.  I split out the task marshaling logic into it's own node instance, basically all I have to do is deploy my repo to a new machine and run node task-server.js to scale out my workers.  I may need to add in some more job searching calls to Kue, because of how I implimented a few things, but that will be easy.

Comment: As an aside, I had basically made this decision when I asked the quesiton, but someone told me to look at AMQP based solutions, and I'm basically at the deadline for decisions so I was hoping to get some feedback.  After researching for the last couple of hours, I decided that I can't find a reason not to use Kue.

Comment: One of the tradeoffs, I think, of using Kue vs a standard message queue protocol such as AMQP is that there are no clients in other languages.

Comment: Are you still using Kue?

Comment: @bob_cobb I've since moved on from that position. While I was there it worked out for us pretty well.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch  -  Thanks for the good explanation on choosing Kue.  Did you get a chance to compare with Kue with https://github.com/mpneuried/rsmq-worker ?

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch came across a similar situation . Could you provide certain metrics towards how "awesome" the throughput is ? Did you carry out any load test whose results or poc one could share ?